# Hover function not working dynamically for each entry

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

So, I'm working on a page and am having a slight issue with setting up a hover funtion dynamically. What I am trying to do is for each entry, create a hover function. I tried everything I could think of but it always seems that each entry gets assigned the same hover function. So, I came to the solution I have now which works in jsfiddle but not on the website I made.

Is there a better way to create a dynamic hover function, or how can I get this to work? Any help is appreciated.

[Link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/afcpb/153/)

[Link to website](http://rbl.net/index.php/institute/new_institute)

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with ExpressionEngine, it doesn't even need to be done with Jquery and can be done purely with CSS.

The problem is you're outputting the JS with every loop of the channel entries instead of using a centralised JS file in your head or bottom of the body html, similar advice would be to move the CSS into a general CSS file instead of inline.

```
.MF {
hide the rollover text
}
.MF:hover {
hide the title and sub-title
show the rollover text
margin-left the arrow
}
```

Comment: This will fix the hover, thanks for the advise. The only problem I see is that I also want to create a click function so when you click an item a separate div animates over the displayed section. I would still need to correlate the entries to include this div in a similar way that I was trying to create the hover function.

Comment: Same issue - the problem you've got is you're duplicating the JS for each entry - you need to use a single JS file and target $(".MF").click(function(e){ ... });